# How to set TimePicker Header Foreground in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, timepicker, uwp-xaml

I can set a Header for my TimePicker, but I can't seem to set the Foreground for that Header. The Foreground property in TimePicker class only changes the text color of the time-selection-box-things.

Looking at the [TimePicker class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker.aspx), I would expect the resource `TimePickerHeaderForeground` to do the job, but I'm honestly not sure how to set that value. Is that a ControlTemplate? How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect the resource 'TimePickerHeaderForeground' to do the job, but I'm honestly not sure how to set that value.

`TimePickerHeaderForeground` is the right way to go. As you can see form the **Remarks** of [TimePicker class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker.aspx), `TimePickerHeaderForeground` is a **Resource key**. So we can define a new resource with this special key to modify header's foreground.

For example, we can define a [SolidColorBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242962) with the key "TimePickerHeaderForeground" in `Page.Resources` like following:

```
<Page ...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TimePickerHeaderForeground">Red</SolidColorBrush>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TimePicker Header="Test" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Should I be able to do this with <UserControl.Resources> instead of <Page.Resources> ? I tried doing that and am not seeing any change in my header color.

Comment: @TS- Using `UserControl.Resources` should also work. Please note that this is newly added  in Windows 10, version 1607 (Windows SDK version 10.0.14393.0). So please make sure your project is target Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393).